# How do I silence the HEAD of a curl request while using the silent flag?

Tags: bash, shell, curl, command-line, pipe

When I run the curl command and direct the data to a file, I get back the content of the site as expected.

```
$ curl "www.site.com" > file.txt
$ head file.txt
Top of site
...
```

However, this command shows a progress bar, which I do not want:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  328k  100  328k    0     0   467k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  467k
```

I can silence the progress bar by passing the `-silent` flag, but then my file output will have head content attached:

```
$ curl -silient "www.site.com" > file.txt
$ head file.txt
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
ETag: "29647904ffa6a6b36cf3483b325138cab9447a13"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: max-age=300
Content-Length: 335978
```

**How can I silence both the progress bar and avoid getting head content sent to the file?**

Based on the provided flags, it seems like I can only get one or the other.

This is what I'm doing right now to solve the problem, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to pipe the progress bar and possibly any errors into /dev/null.

```
curl "www.site.com" > file.txt 2> /dev/null
```

The reason I don't think this is a good idea is because it may interfere with the actual errors that I care about.  I'd like to utilize the `silent` flag if that's what it was intended for.

I've also tried all the same commands using the `-o` to output to a file, but to no prevail.

Comment: `-silient` is a typo and is causing your problem. Either use `--silent` or `-s`. As a general rule long-options use `--` prefixes and not `-` prefixes. So `-silient` is the same as `-slniet`/etc. and is turning on the `-i` option.

Comment: @EtanReisner I can't spell.  This is correct and it solves my problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
curl --silent "www.site.com" > file.txt
```

If you wish, you can use the shorthand `-s`.

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `--silent` with two dashes. Your “option” `-silient` (sic!) enables the `-s`, `-i`, `-l`, `-e`, `-n` and `-t` options.

`-i` is what includes the HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

Using both`-q` and `-s` did the trick.